# Disable auto insertion of equal sign in XAML in VS2013?

Tags: xaml, autocomplete, visual-studio-2013, autoformatting

When I enter `Name` then hit space the editor turns it into `Name="`. I don't want this. I've disabled everything in `Options > XAML > Formatting`.